# anddoid-camera-onActivityResult-Intent null

Tags: android, android-intent, null

I am trying to develop an app which involves capturing an image, cropping it and saving it to Application database. In this process, I encountered an error, which seemed quite common but unclear:

> 'Intent' parameter in the 'onActivityResult' method is null.

Below is the activity code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class ScanActivity extends Activity {
ImageView imgFavorite;

//keep track of camera capture intent
final int CAMERA_CAPTURE = 1;
//captured picture uri
private Uri picUri;
//keep track of cropping intent
final int PIC_CROP = 2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
    imgFavorite = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        String errormesage="Oops-your device doesnt support capturing images!";
        Toast.makeText(ScanActivity.this,errormesage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ContentResolver cr=getContentResolver();
    String imageName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());

    File photo=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),imageName);
    Uri selectedImage=Uri.fromFile(photo);
    Bitmap bp ;
    try{
        //user is returning from capturing an image using the camera
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE) {
            picUri=data.getData();

            //carry out the crop operation
             performCrop(picUri);

            bp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
            imgFavorite.setImageBitmap(bp);
            Toast.makeText(ScanActivity.this,"Captured Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else if (requestCode==PIC_CROP)
        {
            if(data!=null) {
                //get the returned data
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                //get the cropped bitmap
                Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");

                //retrieve a reference to the ImageView
                ImageView picView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

                //display the returned cropped image
                picView.setImageBitmap(thePic);

                // open();
                //1  Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                //startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                //1 startActivityForResult(intent,1);
            }

        }
        else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(logtag,e.toString());
        String errormesage="scan failed";
        Toast.makeText(ScanActivity.this,errormesage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void performCrop(Uri picUri){

  try {
      //call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
      Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
      System.out.println("Past intent");
      //indicate image type and Uri
      cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
      //set crop properties
      cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
      //indicate aspect of desired crop
      cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 2);
      cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
      //indicate output X and Y
      cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 128);
      cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 128);
      //retrieve data on return
      cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
      //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
      startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
      System.out.println("Past start activity for intent");
  }

    catch(Exception e){
        //display an error message
        String errorMessage = "oops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        System.out.println("exception message is :"+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please only include the relevant parts of your code - as it is, there's a lot to look through. Also, which line does the error occur on?

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are [many image cropping libraries](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/45) available. Please use one.

Comment: @Wai ha Lee: I tried to keep the case clear and hence this long code.well, the 'Intent' in 'onActivityResult' is containing null values. all the key fields like 'mData' are null.On running this code, the 'catch'  block is executed, saying, 'scan failed'.